# JMockit generate coverage report from command line

Tags: java, code-coverage, jmockit

I have the following command :

```
 java -javaagent:jmockit.jar -cp ./out:junit.jar:hamcrest-core-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestCompareNumbers
```

where TestCompareNumbers is my test class for which i want a coverage report.

The result is :

```
    JUnit version 4.12-beta-3
.....
Time: 0.011

OK (5 tests)
```

But a coverage report file hasnt been generated. I guess that Ive missed an option, I searched on google but i have no answer for that. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your are looking for coverage using jmockit for a non-jmockit based code you should use javaagent= jmockit-coverage.jar

From the jmockit documentation

> When not using the JMockit mocking APIs, code coverage can still be activated without adding any jar to the classpath. Instead, run with "-javaagent:/jmockit-coverage.jar" as a JVM initialization parameter.